# Date format conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have 2 tables which I want to join based on date but date format present in both of them is different.
In one table date is mentioned as 10-10-2020 and in other it is 10-Oct-20. My preferred format would be 10-10-2020 or 10/10/2020.
How can this be achieved using SQL Server?

Comment: The best solution would be to keep dates in a `date` datatype. If that is not possible, do the conversion in the join condition.

Comment: If you store your dates as dates instead of strings you won't have this issue. Since you appear to have used strings, just use convert or cast to ensure they are the same. There are hundreds of questions and answers out there on converting date formats.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, change the column that has the "oct" version to the same type as the first one or a date column. This will make the join easier since its not required to transform each row.

If that is not possible you need a hardcoded translation for the (I assume) 12 different Strings describing the months to the equivalent number 1-12. That will allow you to replace the "oct" part with a number. Then you should be able to use cast( as date) to make it a proper Date column.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `try_cast()` function as shown below:

```
select try_cast('10-Oct-20' as date)
```

The output will be as shown below:

```
DtDate
-----------
2020-10-10
```

For displaying the date in different format you can use one of the method as suggested in this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

For simplicity see the below query:

```
select convert(varchar(10), try_cast('10-Nov-20' as date), 10)  
select convert(varchar(10), try_cast('10-Nov-20' as date), 5)
```